# Keyboard Shortcut to Maximize Current Window / Application in MacOS

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I saw a post here about this, but it is 7 years old and the solution doesn't work in the newest version of MacOS. Does know how to currently do this?

I have to clarify that I do not want to set the application to full screen, but to maximize it the same way one does by holding option and then clicking that + symbol.

Comment: Same as 7 years ago, there's no key command. Opt/double click on any window corner is your best bet, better than Opt/Green button.

Comment: Please provide a link to the previous solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is none but you can set one yourself. Just to validate, I did this now on MacOS 11.3.1 and it works:

1. Open *System Preferences*
2. Select *Keyboard*
3. Switch to the *Shortcuts* tab
4. Choose *App Shortcuts* from the list on the left
5. Click on '+'
6. Choose 'All Applications'
7. Type in 'Zoom' into the *Menu Title* entry field
8. Select the shortcut field and press the shortcut you want to use.

Note that it looks like application shortcuts have precedence, so you may need several trials to find one that is not used by the software you usually run.

Comment: Seems like that is what the OP asked. Maximize takes more space and that can be also set to a shortcut with the same method.

Comment: oh, sorry. My bad - no they don't want maximise, they want that 'approximation of maximise' designed to irritate;))